# How could i count some punctuation marks which the function ispunct doesn't have

Tags: c++

```
      for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
       if(ispunct(s[i]))
```

I need to write function in which i have to count punctuation marks, as follow; but ispunct function doesn't have them all
 .  ,  -  ;  :  '  "  (  )  ...  ?  !

I tried to use the strchr, but I couldn't find the " ' " 
These from above are "only" considered, how I could actually count them ??

Thanks!

Comment: Show the code for `ispunct` ... That's the relevant part of code ...

Comment: It's a standard function.

Comment: @EluciusFTW: I think that refers to `ispunct` in the cctype header.

Comment: Well then write an own method wrapping that one, which will also check for characters that are not included in `ispunct`...

Comment: Yeah, its the function from cctype header, but if I use this i can't find all the  "puncts" i have to count.

Comment: I'm a little curious about exactly what your problem is - `ispunct()` will return true for all of the characters in your list (except for `...` which isn't an ASCII character - I'm not sure what you meant with that in your list of punctuation characters). Although `ispunct()` will turn true for some other characters as well.

Comment: Also, `strchr()` will have no problem finding `'` as long as you pass it the correct argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a string with all the signs you want to search for:

```
std::string searchPunct=".,-;:'\"()?!"
```

Test eache single character of the of the input string, if it is member of `searchPunct`, by using [`std::string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find):

```
size_t countPunct( const char *s )
{
    static const std::string searchPunct = ".,-;:'\"()?!";
    size_t count = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < strlen( s ); i++ )
    {
        if ( searchPunct.find( s[i] ) != string::npos )
            count ++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just list all the characters you care about, and use `find_first_of` to identify if the character is there. Something like this:

```
bool isPunctuation(char c)
{
   static const std::string punctuations(".,-;:'\"()?");
   if (punctuations.find_first_of(c) != std::string::npos)
   {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: @Mats I wanted to answer similarly, but then realized that there are locales. Couldn't it be done with setting the right one? Or custom facet?

Comment: @LogicStuff: Of course, that's another way to solve it - but I'm not 100% sure that this would be a better/simpler solution.